# Laravel Backpack - File upload is not triggering mutator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-9

I'm running Laravel 9 on the latest Backpack. I've been trying to add a file upload field to my form, but I'm running into issues. I've added the following to my CRUD controller:

```
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::setValidation(BuildRequest::class);
    // CRUD::field('id');
    CRUD::addField([   // Upload
        'name'      => 'firmware',
        'label'     => 'Firmware-file',
        'type'      => 'upload',
        'upload'    => true,
        'disk'      => 'uploads',
    ]);
}
```

As well as added the following mutator in my Model class:

```
public function setFirmwareAttribute($value)
{
    dd();
    $attribute_name = "firmware";
    $disk = "public";
    $destination_path = "folder_1/subfolder_1";

    $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
}
```

I also have a database column named "firmware" to hold the path to the file. I'm having the issue that it seems the mutator is never called. The file also never gets placed in the appropriate folder. I also get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'firmware' doesn't have a
> default value

I was hinting that my firmware string is not being filled on creation. Making the firmware-column nullable in the migration fixes this error, but the entry remains "NULL" when trying to upload a file. I've also added a dd(); to see if the mutator ever gets entered, but this does not seem to be the case. I've also tried changing up the Mutator syntax to be Laravel 9 compliant, but this also does not help. Also, in the migration guide from Laravel 8 to 9, I couldn't find any mention of updating the mutator functions, so I'm assuming the new mutator syntax is backward compatible. Any clue as to what I'm missing here?

EDIT: I've changed my mutator as to be up to date with Laravel 9 and the behavior is exactly the same:

```
    protected function firmware(): Attribute
{
    dd();
    return Attribute::make(
        set: function ($value) {
            $attribute_name = "firmware";
            $disk = "public";
            $destination_path = "folder_1/subfolder_1";

            $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
        },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the firmware attribute in the $fillable property of your model to make it mass assignable.